# Optimize function for finding a nested property in an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript, optimization

I made the following function which traverses an object recursively  and tries to find if a property exists in that object. If it does, it returns that property and null if it is not found:

```
export const findNestedPropertyInObject = (sourceObject: any, targetKey: string) => {
  let results: any;
  const maxIterations = 100;
  let currentIteration = 0;
  const searchInObject = (obj: any, targetKey: string) => {
    const keys = obj.length ? [] : Object.keys(obj);
    if (keys && keys.length) {
      if (keys.includes(targetKey)) {
        results = obj[targetKey];
        return;
      } else {
        keys.forEach((key: string) => {
          if (currentIteration >= maxIterations) {
            return;
          }
          currentIteration++;
          searchInObject(obj[key], targetKey);
        });
      }
    }
  };

  searchInObject(sourceObject, targetKey);
  return results;
};
```

this is the sample object:

```
const aggregations = {
  most_used_skills: {
    doc_count: 388,
    skill: {
      doc_count_error_upper_bound: 10,
      sum_other_doc_count: 325,
      buckets: [
        {
          key: 'C++ Programming Language',
          doc_count: 15,
        },
        {
          key: 'Javascript',
          doc_count: 14,
        },
        {
          key: 'ExtJS',
          doc_count: 12,
        },
        {
          key: 'Amazon Web Services',
          doc_count: 11,
        },
        {
          key: 'Android',
          doc_count: 11,
        },
      ],
    },
  },
};
```

this is how i am invoking it:

```
console.log(findNestedPropertyInObject(aggregations, 'buckets'));
```

My question is that, how can i optimize this method? What safety checks can i add to this to make it more fault tolerant and robust?

Comment: This SE would be more suitable for your question: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
export const findNestedPropertyInObject = (sourceObject: any, targetKey: string) => {
let results: any;
const maxIterations = 100;
let currentIteration = 0;
const searchInObject = (obj: any, targetKey: string) => {

    const keys = (obj.length)? obj : Object.keys(obj); // if obj is object get keys as an array
    if ( currentIteration < maxIterations && typeof keys === 'object') // checking if it actually an Array (js treat array as object type)
    {   
        if (keys.includes(targetKey))
        {
            results = obj[targetKey];
            currentIteration = maxIterations; // to stop recursive calling
            return; //optional
        } 
        else
        {
            keys.forEach((key: any) => {
            currentIteration++;
            const innerkeys = (obj[key])? obj[key] : key; // to check if 'key' is key of object or object itself
            searchInObject(innerkeys, targetKey);
            });
        }
    }
};

searchInObject(sourceObject, targetKey); 
return results
};
```

Comment: I have done some changes in loop and to check inner array of object or other array.

Comment: Hi @aryan, Thank you so much for the contribution. However, it would be even more helpful if you provide some insight into what your code is doing and how is it helpful. What changes have you made to it and how is better than the original code.

Comment: Hi @HussainAliAkbar, your original code does not look in array of objects, so I added line -"const innerkeys = (obj[key])? obj[key] : key;" so it can make a recursive call to function with object only (if "key" is a key of sourceObject then pass it, else pass the key as it is, means key is object itself).